# How to view a .key file on windows

Tags: private-key

I have a .key file that is supposedly a 2048 bit private key used to sign an android app.

What windows tool can I use to view the content of this key file ?

Answer (score 1):

The .key is a zip archive: if you unzip you may be able to see a thumbnail for each slide, so just rename the .key file to .zip and unzip it to see the slide thumbnails or you can convert it to pdf to view on windows using the following:
[www.zamzar.com/](http://www.zamzar.com/)

Comment: "a .key file that is supposedly a 2048 bit private key" - how is that related to thumbnails?